# How to test side-effect when state hook is passed to a child component using React and jest?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I want to test a child component, but it relies on state (hooks) from the parent.

the child receives `isModalOpen` and `setIsModalOpen` as properties. Each time `isModalOpen` changes, the `useEffect` inside `Child` will trigger. However, when I try to test the `Child` component by itself, I'm not able to force a state change triggering the `useEffect` hook. How can I achieve this without having to render the `Parent` in the test environment?

In the below example, I'm able to make the test pass by rendering `Parent`. I want to only render `Child`, and still make the test pass.

```js
function Child({ isModalOpen, setIsModalOpen }) {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("is the modal open?", isModalOpen);
  }, [isModalOpen]);

  return (
    <button data-testId="myBtn" onClick={() => setIsModalOpen(!isModalOpen)}>
      Click to {isModalOpen ? "close" : "open"} modal
    </button>
  );
}

function Parent() {
    const [isModalOpen, setIsModalOpen] = useState(false);
    return <Child isModalOpen={isModalOpen} setIsModalOpen={setIsModalOpen} />;
}
```

Test:

```js
it("React test", () => {
  let isModalOpen = false;
  const mockFunction = jest.fn((val) => (isModalOpen = val));

  const { queryByTestId } = render(
    <Child isModalOpen={isModalOpen} setIsModalOpen={mockFunction} />
  );

  const btnEl = queryByTestId("myBtn");

  btnEl.click();
  expect(btnEl.innerHTML).toEqual("Click to close modal");

  // -----
  // -----
  // -----
  // ----- The below code works
  // const { queryByTestId } = render(<Parent />);

  // const btnEl = queryByTestId("myBtn");

  // btnEl.click();
  // expect(btnEl.innerHTML).toEqual("Click to close modal");
});
```

Here is a working example of the above code snippet:
https://codesandbox.io/s/jest-test-forked-cjm3r?file=/index.test.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually to sum it up, what you're trying to test is not related to hooks if the hook is passed this into the child. Think of the child as your **subject** under test; in other words its the only thing you're trying to test. The "hook" by definition is irrelevant. You pass in a function and you can assert that a function that has been called with the proper value.

Which to sum it up, you have two cases

1. When the modal is *open* and you click on the button "Click to close modal" button, the modal will close or otherwise known is calling your mock function with *false*.
2. When the modal is *closed* and you click on the button "Click to close modal" button, the modal will open or otherwise known is calling your mock function with *true*.

I made minor edits to the test that you have above to demonstrate this. Feel free to copy and paste it in and check for yourself and let me know if you have questions.

Note: Copied and pasted from the sandbox link with minor modifications to not diverge too much from the original code.

```js
it("closes the modal when clicking on the button", () => {
    function Child({ isModalOpen, setIsModalOpen }) {
        useEffect(() => {
            console.log("is the modal open?", isModalOpen);
        }, [isModalOpen]);

        return (
            <button data-testId="myBtn" onClick={() => setIsModalOpen(!isModalOpen)}>
                Click to {isModalOpen ? "close" : "open"} modal
            </button>
        );
    }

    // notice the mock here doesn't take arguments
    const mockFunction = jest.fn();

    const { queryByTestId } = render(
        // notice that I've set the initial value for isModal to true
        <Child isModalOpen={true} setIsModalOpen={mockFunction} />
    );

    const btnEl = queryByTestId("myBtn");

    btnEl.click();
    expect(btnEl.innerHTML).toEqual("Click to close modal");

    // the assertion here
    expect(mockFunction).toHaveBeenCalledWith(false);
});

it("opens the modal when clicking on the bottom", () => {
    function Child({ isModalOpen, setIsModalOpen }) {
        useEffect(() => {
            console.log("is the modal open?", isModalOpen);
        }, [isModalOpen]);

        return (
            <button data-testId="myBtn" onClick={() => setIsModalOpen(!isModalOpen)}>
                Click to {isModalOpen ? "close" : "open"} modal
            </button>
        );
    }

    const mockFunction = jest.fn();

    const { queryByTestId } = render(
        // notice that I've set the initial value for isModal to false
        <Child isModalOpen={false} setIsModalOpen={mockFunction} />
    );

    const btnEl = queryByTestId("myBtn");

    btnEl.click();
    expect(btnEl.innerHTML).toEqual("Click to open modal");

    // the assertion here
    expect(mockFunction).toHaveBeenCalledWith(true);
});
```

Comment: Good explanation. I would just suggest to remove the `Child` component declaration from the tests to avoid confusion. You should import your component in the test file, not create it there :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think I should have added some more details to the question, but I tried to keep it as simple as possible. There are some side-effects I want to verify, and those side-effects are only triggered after the state has changed (inside the useEffect). After reading this answer, I assume that I cannot verify these side-effect directly? For my simple example, the side-effect is to verify that the text inside the button has changed.

Comment: Hi @John, it feels like your test approach is what needs to be adjusted. If you are only testing the child, you should mock the different states and assert that your component is rendering/reacting in the right way for that given state (as showed in this answer).
Trying to test the state change itself, is testing React code, which is not necessary :)

If you do have a very specific reason to test that though, then you should test by rendering the parent, which would be really testing your code. Hope it makes sense.

Comment: This article may help with more info: https://kentcdodds.com/blog/how-to-know-what-to-test#how-does-this-apply-to-react

Comment: @BrunoMonteiro I would agree with that and fixing beforeEach's and describe's. I just wanted to keep the changes to a minimum so it would be easier for the asker to understand :). Simply copy and pasting from the code in the link provided so he could test for himself.

Comment: @WillC Ah, the code was from his sandbox...got it :)

Comment: @John Adding another possibility to what Bruno mentioned earlier that is if you really really wanted to test the "side effect" to make sure the integration is correct, you'd test that that the modal is actually open and not the states. In this scenario, checking the modal is "toBeInTheDocument" or something similar for each scenario via the React Testing Library.

Comment: @BrunoMonteiro Thanks for the comment and the article. I guess that makes sense. Maybe I need to think differently in the way I test my components. I don't want to test the React state change itself, just the side-effect, but it makes sense that I should then test the component in the new state.